# Ubuntusteam SDL launch commands [18.04][dualscreen]

Tags: multiple-monitors, games, steam, fullscreen

I am trying to launch a borderless fullscreen window on a specific monitor in steam. The game(EU4) I am trying to launch opens in the wrong window when launching in borderless fullscreen. However, it opens in the correct window in fullscreen mode. I can't seem to be able to specify a monitor to launch it in. Furthermore, I can not drag or move the window when in borderless fullscreen.

I have 2 main questions:

1. Is there an SDL command that will allow me to specify a monitor to open a game in?
2. Is there a way to move a borderless fullscreen window when the game is already running?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I forgot to mention that but I tried working with fullscreen and I can move the window using Super key. However that does not work for borderless unfortunately.